# Bot de telegram. Error al ejecutar una función de enviar mensaje

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

tengo hecho un bot para telegram el cual hace x cosas, como sumar, dividr, darte info para los comandos, imagenes randoms de perros,etc...
La cuestion es que tuve que cambiar varias lineas para poder meter la parte de generar imágenes para que luego el bot te las muestre

```
import logging
import requests
import re
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, InlineQueryHandler

#Habilito el login
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

#Al hacer click en iniciar saludamos al usuario
def iniciar(update, bot):
    """Aqui le mandamos el mensaje"""
    bot.message.reply_text('''Hola soy un bot creado por Moha de M03 1 de DAW.
Escribe /ayuda para que veas lo que puedo hacer :D, espero ayudarte. XDXD''')

def ayudar(update, bot):
    """Aqui digo lo que sabe hacer mi bot"""
    bot.message.reply_text('''Informacion
    /sumar X Y "Aqui el bot le suma y le da el resultado.
    /dividir X Y "Aqui el bot le divide y le da el resultado.
    /porcentaje X Y "Aqui el bot le da el porcentaje de un valor X.
    /ayudaporcentaje "Mas informacion para el uso de porcentaje."
    /perro "Te muestra una imagen aletoria de un perro."''')

def sumar(context, update, bot):
    try:
        numero1 = int(context.args[0])
        numero2 = int(context.args[1])

        suma = numero1 + numero2
        bot.message.reply_text('La suma es '+str(suma))

    except (IndexError, ValueError):
        update.message.reply_text('Por favor utiliza dos numeros')

def dividir(update, context):
    try:
        numero1 = int(context.args[0])
        numero2 = int(context.args[1])

        div= numero1 / numero2
        update.message.reply_text('La division da '+str(div))

    except (IndexError, ValueError):
        update.message.reply_text('Por favor utiliza dos numeros')


def texto(update, bot):
    bot.message.reply_text("Escriba /ayuda para ver mas informacion.")

def porcentaje (update, context):
    try:
        numero1 = int(context.args[0])
        numero2 = int(context.args[1])
        resultado= numero1*numero2/100
        update.message.reply_text("El "+str(context.args[1])+'% de '+str(context.args[0])+' es '+str(resultado))
    except (IndexError, ValueError):
        update.message.reply_text('Por favor, escriba correctamente los valores para poder calcular el porcentaje si necesit ayuda haga click en /ayudaporcentaje.')

def ayudaporcentaje (update, bot):
    bot.message.reply_text('''
    Necesita un valor X y un valor I, el valor
    X seria el valor completo y la I el porcentaje que quiere usted saber.
    Ejemplo: quiero saber el 10% de 100
    /porcentaje 100 10 (importante el orden primero el valor y luego el porcentaje.) 
    el bot le respondera con 10 como resultado de porcentaje.''')

def get_url():
    contents = requests.get('https://random.dog/woof.json').json()    
    url = contents['url']
    return url

def get_image_url():
    allowed_extension = ['jpg','jpeg','png']
    file_extension = ''
    while file_extension not in allowed_extension:
        url = get_url()
        file_extension = re.search("([^.]*)$",url).group(1).lower()
    return url

def perro(bot, update):
    url = get_image_url()
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo=url)

def main():
    """Aqui iniciamos el bot y lo que hacemos es crear un token para poder iniciar el bot en telegram"""
    session = Updater("TOKEN xxxxxxxx")
    # el token lo guardamos en un a variable llamada botm3
    botm3 = session.dispatcher


    botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("Iniciar", iniciar))
    botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("Ayuda", ayudar))
    botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("Sumar", sumar))
    botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("Dividir", dividir))
    botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("Dividir", dividir))
    botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("ayudaporcentaje", ayudaporcentaje))
    botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("porcentaje", porcentaje))
    botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("perro", perro))
    botm3.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, texto))
    session.start_polling()

    #Aqui empieza el bot
    #sesion.start_polling()

    #Aqui decimos que es un bulce y que no pare hasta que le demos a ctrl+c 
    session.idle()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Me muestra el seguiente error el cual me hace petar el bot y asi deje de  funcionar, el mensaje del fallo es el seguiente:

```
builtins.TypeError: sumar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bot'
```

ya he probado lo siguiente en el código y nada a ver si alguien tiene la solución:

```
def sumar(context, update):
    try:
        numero1 = int(context.args[0])
        numero2 = int(context.args[1])

        suma = numero1 + numero2
        update.message.reply_text('La suma es '+str(suma))

    except (IndexError, ValueError):
        update.message.reply_text('Por favor utiliza dos numeros')
```

También he probado esto:

```
def sumar(context, update, bot):
    try:
        numero1 = int(context.args[0])
        numero2 = int(context.args[1])

        suma = numero1 + numero2
        bot.message.reply_text('La suma es '+str(suma))

    except (IndexError, ValueError):
        bot.message.reply_text('Por favor utiliza dos numeros')
```

Tambien he hecho lo siguente pero me da error de atributos:

```
def sumar(context, bot):
    try:
        numero1 = int(context.args[0])
        numero2 = int(context.args[1])

        suma = numero1 + numero2
        bot.message.reply_text('La suma es '+str(suma))

    except (IndexError, ValueError):
        bot.message.reply_text('Por favor utiliza dos numeros')
```

Comment: Se supone que la callback debe tener la firma `sumar(update, context)`.

Comment: @FJSevilla Yo lo he porbado y nada ya hice el   sumar(update, context) y me da el siguente  `builtins.AttributeError: 'Update' object has no attribute 'args' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la versión actual de python-telegram-bot, las funciones callback que son asignadas como CommandHandler y MessageHandler usan `(update, context)` como parámetros. Dentro de `context` puedes obtener varias cosas como `args` y `bot`, por ejemplo: `context.bot.send_message(CHATID, "un texto")`, pero en tu ejemplo en particular `context.bot.send_message()` es reemplazable por `update.message.reply_text()`. Aun así vamos con un código que funcione:

```
import logging
import requests
import re
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, InlineQueryHandler

def sumar(update, context):
    try:
        numero1 = int(context.args[0])
        numero2 = int(context.args[1])

        suma = numero1 + numero2
        context.bot.send_message(update.message.chat.id,'La suma es '+str(suma))

    except (IndexError, ValueError):
        update.message.reply_text('Por favor utiliza dos numeros')

def get_url():
    contents = requests.get('https://random.dog/woof.json').json()    
    url = contents['url']
    return url

def get_image_url():
    allowed_extension = ['jpg','jpeg','png']
    file_extension = ''
    while file_extension not in allowed_extension:
        url = get_url()
        file_extension = re.search("([^.]*)$",url).group(1).lower()
    return url

def perro(update, context):
    url = get_image_url()
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    context.bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo=url)

def main():
    updater = Updater("TOKEN", use_context=True)
    # el token lo guardamos en un a variable llamada botm3
    botm3 = updater.dispatcher

    botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("Sumar", sumar))
    botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("perro", perro))

    updater.start_polling()

    #Aqui decimos que es un bulce y que no pare hasta que le demos a ctrl+c 
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Ojo con la modificación en la función `main`, ahí queda funcional para trabajar con la versión 12 que permite usar con los detalles que mencioné en un comienzo, de otro modo tienes una mezcolanza de versiones. Ahora solo falta actualizar el resto de las funciones.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda pero sigue fallando, ya no se que hacer :_D @SergioR

Comment: Probaste con el ejemplo mínimo que puse? Agregaste tu token? Qué error lanza?

Comment: Sigo en pruebas, no se he aplicado bien lo que usted me dijo.
Si usted quiere le puedo dejarte el toke para que usted vea, @SergioR

Comment: El token es personal, evita pasárselo a personas que no conozcas ;)

Comment: No pasa nada siempre lo puedo eliminar @SergioR

Comment: nombre del bot= (aquí arroba)moha_m03_1bot @SergioR

Comment: Mira, copia el código que puse en un nuevo script y ejecútalo con tu token y háblale a tu bot. Actualmente solo funciona con `/sumar numero1 numero2` para mostrar la estructura básica, usar argumentos y usar bot. Faltaría adecuar el resto de las funciones.

Comment: Le comento, yo de sumar y las otras operaciones pude hacerlo fucionar pero al juntar con el comando de mandar una imagen de un perro no fucciona @SergioR

Comment: SI usted ejecuta el comando de perro, el programa peta y si lo adaptas a la imagen te falla el resto y solo funciona la imagen  @SergioR

Comment: Deja revisar y agrego esa función a mi respuesta, pero en un vistazo a la rápida tienes que actualizar los parámetro de la función `perro` y llamar a `bot` como `context.bot`.

Comment: No entiendo a que se refiere @SergioR

Comment: Prueba con el nuevo código.

Comment: Muchas gracias @SergioR ya funciona